# avoid "if" statement in program to draw a numbers tree

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

The following is a program to draw a numbers tree, but I can't avoid the "if" statement

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import sys
def xmasTree():
    centre=35
    inicial=1
    level=input("¿Triangle height? \n\t")
    for height in range (inicial,level+1): 
        for index in range(1,centre-height):
            sys.stdout.write(' ') 
        sys.stdout.write(str(inicial)) 
        for index in range(inicial+1,height): 
            sys.stdout.write(str(index))
        for index in range(height,inicial,-1):
            sys.stdout.write(str(index))
        if height>1:
            sys.stdout.write('1')
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
xmasTree()
```

*Edit: Finally i found what i wanted. Obviously i didn't explained myself correctly. In any case, thank you all!

Here is the correct code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import sys
def xmasTree():
    centre=35
    sep=1
    initial=1
    level=input("¿Triangle height? \n\t")
    for height in range (1,level+1): 
        for index in range(1,centre-height):
            sys.stdout.write(' ') 
        sys.stdout.write(str(sep))
        for index in range(initial+1,height+1):
          sys.stdout.write(str(index))
        for index in range(height+1,initial+1,-1):
             sys.stdout.write(str(index-2))
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

And the correct output:

```
                         1
                        121
                       12321
                      1234321
                     123454321
                    12345654321
                   1234567654321
                  123456787654321
                 12345678987654321
```

Comment: I'm not sure why we needed to know that.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid it?

Comment: I'm new to python and trying to figure out how things work. Sorry if this is not the right place to answer this kind of questions

Comment: I want to avoid this because i think this is not an elegant solution

Comment: @user3065495 it's ok to ask questions about problems\errors in your code, just try to clarify your problem so we will be able to help you. by saying `avoid “if”` it's not clear. It will be much clear if you'll print the expected output for example.

Comment: Thanks @KobiK, it's my first question and as i thought the program was very simple, would not need to explain it better. In the future i'll try to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function:

```
def xmasTree(n,v=0):
    if n > 0:
        xmasTree(n-2, v+1)
        print " " * v + "".join(str(x%10) for x in range(n))
xmasTree(31)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @perreal your function is great, i'll try to use it to get the result i need, which is 1,121,12321,1234321... Sorry for the rest if i disturbed you.

Answer (score 0):

```
height = 5
inicial = 2    
for l in range(initial, height):
     line = ''.join( 
                    str( max(l-i, i-l)+1 ) for i in range(2*l+1)
               )
     # {:^35} centers a string within 35 characters, look up python string formatting
     print( '{:^35}'.format(line) )
```

**Output**

```
            212                
           32123               
          4321234              
         543212345
```